# Why is my Acer Aspire E15 running slower when plugged in than on battery?

Tags: windows-8.1, performance, battery, acer-aspire

I am working on an [Acer Aspire E15 (ES1-511-C590)](http://www.pcworld.com/product/1429275/acer-aspire-es1-511-c590-notebook.html) running Windows 8.1 X64 with all the latest patches. It is running significantly slower while plugged in than when running off battery.

Yes, this is counter-intuitive, and yes, I have checked the power settings.

No, this is not a subjective analysis. I ran [PerformanceTest 8](http://www.passmark.com/download/pt_download.htm) on the system both plugged in and while running off battery. Here are the figures from each test:

| Category | On Battery Power | While Charging |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Overall | 600 | 186 |
| CPU | 1024 | 275 |
| 2D | 193 | 48 |
| 3D | 152 | 41 |
| Memory | 757 | 772 |
| Disk | 681 | 759 |

Comment: Can you show the power settings details for both cases? How high is the frequency of your CPU reported by the Task Manager/cpu-z?

Comment: Is the battery also used when the laptop is plugged in , or without the battery ?

Comment: Is your power outlet properly grounded?

Answer (score 2):

1. Have you adjusted the settings in *Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings*, *Advance options*, which have separate options for *On battery* and *Plugged in*? That is the most likely cause of the issue, particularly active vs. passive cooling in *Processor power management*. See [13 Ways to Save Power](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-tweak-advanced-settings-power-plan-windows-7) for more information, and [Power Options](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/51043-power-options-add-remove-system-cooling-policy.html) if the cooling policy is not shown.
2. Some Windows maintenance tasks, e.g. disk optimization, can be deferred while on battery, but resume with vengeance when plugged in. Check *Task Manager* (or *Sysinternals Process Explorer*) to see if there are running *Scheduled Tasks* using up CPU time. If that is the issue, let the tasks finish to keep the laptop healthy, and then it should speed up.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was because of the more aggressive thermal throttling that occurred as a result of the battery heating up from charging.

By cooling down the internals by, for example, holding the bottom case of the laptop up to a fan for a couple of seconds, the throttling would stop.

Answer (score 0):

Some win8.1 versions are configured to safe power while not plugged in so it will enabled some tasks to keep your computer "healthy". If you want to disable the you can refer to [this tutorial.](http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-2120194/enable-disable-automatic-maintenance-windows.html/)

Comment: This is essentially just a copy of the second point from the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is really weird...

I found some references to event logs sometimes causing these issues, so I cleared out some of the event logs on the system and now the performance test when plugged in is similar to that when running on battery (I have both set to utilize the most system resources).

I have no clue why this would be so...but it seems to be.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem!! I solved it by:

Control Panel - Power Options - Change plan settings (on the right of the your power plan) - Change advanced power settings - scroll down and click on 'processor power management' - Maximum processor state - the 'plugged in' option was 0% while the 'on battery' was 100%, I simply put 100% in 'plugged in' (and kept 'on battery' 100% as well) and it worked instantly...I was using the internet with no hassle whatsoever and the laptop itself wasn't slow anymore :)

Hope this helps.